# PHP will not render - Python Tornado

Tags: php, python, html, tornado

I'm using a tornado framework to host an html project and wish to incorporate some php functionality (pretty much so I can submit and handle forms without refreshing the page).

In my efforts, I have discovered that php will not render at all, so I whipped up a stub viewable through `http://localhost/static/test.php`. Upon [viewing the source code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nL0F1.png) through inspect element, it appears as though the php code has been commented out...

Anyway I'm just wondering if anyone has come across this issue and if so, how they overcame it. Is it just that PHP and Tornado do not agree with one another?

(Indeed, PHP is installed and functional on this machine. The expected output is observed upon executing the `php test.php` command in Terminal.

Comment: Without seeing the original code, it is difficult to tell. Can you upload the code?

Comment: Are you running the PHP on some sort of webserver (Apache? or the built in server?) It looks like the PHP code is not interpreted.

Comment: If you're using Tornado just to serve static HTML and want to execute PHP, a general-purpose webserver like nginx or Apache is going to serve you much better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tornado is a Python web framework, it is intended for application development using Python. If you want a web server that executes PHP, then Tornado isn't the right solution, I'd recommend Apache or another web server that's well-suited to executing PHP applications.

Comment: Alright thanks for the response, I'll pursue the recommended.